# Table View Cell - UITableView - Cannot show multiple rows in detailed view

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview

I am using Tableview to display **Name** from `recipes Array` which works great and displays all name in table view from `recipes Array`. When i tap on one of the recipe it displays the name on detailed view.

What i am stuck of is, how to display other fields in the `detailed view`.I have an Array ( `array name: ingredients` ) which has contents of that specific recipe, example ingredients.

**I tried with**

```
cell.textLabel.text = [ingredients objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

**RecipeDetailViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface RecipeDetailViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *recipeLabel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *recipeName;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *recipeCountry;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *recipeCountryName;

@end
```

**but it doesn't show anything in RecipeBookViewController.m
Here is my Original code**

```
#import "RecipeBookViewController.h"
#import "RecipeDetailViewController.h"

@interface RecipeBookViewController ()

@end

@implementation RecipeBookViewController {
    NSArray *recipes;
}

@synthesize tableView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    NSData *allCourseData=[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.kivaws.org/v1/loans/search.json?status=fundraising"]];

    NSError *error;
    NSMutableDictionary *JsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization
                                       JSONObjectWithData:allCourseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                       error:&error];

    NSArray *loans = JsonObject[@"loans"];
    // Create a new loans array for store the new items
    NSMutableArray *newLoans = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSMutableArray *arrCountry = [NSMutableArray array];


    for (NSDictionary *loan in loans) {
        NSNumber *ident = loan[@"id"];
        NSString *name = loan[@"name"];
        NSDictionary *description = loan[@"description"];
        NSDictionary *location = loan[@"location"];
        NSString *country = location[@"country"];
        NSString *status = loan[@"status"];

        NSDictionary *geo = location[@"geo"];
        NSString *geoprint = geo[@"pairs"];

        [newLoans addObject:name];
        [arrCountry addObject:country];
    }
    recipes=newLoans;

}


- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [recipes count];
}

//Display Name in Detail View
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"RecipeCell";

    //Displays name
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [recipes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}


- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showRecipeDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        RecipeDetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.recipeName = [recipes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
}


@end
```

**RecipeDetailViewController.m**

```
#import "RecipeDetailViewController.h"

@interface RecipeDetailViewController ()

@end

@implementation RecipeDetailViewController

@synthesize recipeLabel;
@synthesize recipeName;
@synthesize recipeCountry;
@synthesize recipeCountryName;


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Set the Label text with the selected recipe
    recipeLabel.text = recipeName;
    recipeCountry.text=recipeCountryName;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

Here are the screenshots of both Views

[image]
[image]

Comment: You need to show us the code that displays the detail view.

Comment: @deadbeef i added the code for RecipeDetailViewController.m

Comment: Show where you are navigating to RecipeDetailVIewController and also show the your main/ingredients array data.

Comment: Show your 'didSelectRowAtIndexPath' delegate method.

Comment: @Shoaib code updated

Comment: @the_UB all M files updated with required h file

Comment: Currently you are not able to display anything using 'recipeCountry.text'.right?

Comment: try alloc the recipes.. NSArray *recipes = [[NSArray alloc] init]; in the viewDidLoad

Comment: @the_UB recipeCountry.text doesn't display anything

Comment: @snksnk it doesn't work

Comment: @Shoaib has given the correct way of doing it...try that and ask if any problem occurs.

Comment: NSLog everything to see where you lose that data.. On each step

Comment: @Shoaib  am getting error i.imgur.com/h27PQu5.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changes in your loop;

```
for (NSDictionary *loan in loans) {
        NSNumber *ident = loan[@"id"];
        NSString *name = loan[@"name"];
        NSDictionary *description = loan[@"description"];
        NSDictionary *location = loan[@"location"];
        NSString *country = location[@"country"];
        NSString *status = loan[@"status"];

        NSDictionary *geo = location[@"geo"];
        NSString *geoprint = geo[@"pairs"];

        [newLoans addObject:@[
          @"name":name,
          @"description":description,
          @"country ":country 
        ]]; // Same way add all keys

        //Or
        /*
        NSMutableDictionary* dicData = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        newLoans[@"name"] = name;
        newLoans[@"description"] = description;
        newLoans[@"country"] = country;
        [newLoans addObject:dicData];
        */

    }
    recipes=newLoans;
```

Change when retrieving;

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   . . . 
   NSDictionary * dict = [recipes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   cell.textLabel.text = dict[@"name"];

    return cell;
}
```

Same way pass the complete dictionary to the RecipeDetailViewController and show other information there.

Comment: The idea is to have a dictionary in your array instead of a single string. I did not get chance to test the code in xcode so you have to correct syntax errors by your own if any. BTW updated the post.

Comment: my code is already working with   
cell.textLabel.text = [recipes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
my  question is how do it add one more Array with countryname in it as 

cell.textLabel.text = [countryname objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];